# "Unique/Inherited" RKObjectLoaderDelegate for all my controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios6, restkit

So I am kind of new to RestKit and I have a question regarding the delegates in the controllers. I see that if a ViewController inherits RKObjectLoaderDelegate, it needs to implement the method:

```
    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Now, If I wanted that same function everywhere (i.e.: in all my ViewControllers that are ObjectLoader Delegates), how would I do that? I don't necessarily want to have that code in 20 different views... I thought about creating a RKObjectLoaderDelegate class and create that class all the time, but then I would have to  change the delegate of the ViewController every single time and it is a pain... Any ideas?! Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting different versions of this function in each controller or will it all be the same?

Comment: They will be the same...

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom object that inherits from UIViewController and adopts the RKObjectLoaderDelegate protocol. Add the desired implementation of the `objectLoader:didFailWithError:` function to this new object. Now, just have your view controllers inherit from the new object instead of UIViewController. This should allow all of the view controllers to use the same function.